# Is there front facing camera support with ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, arscnview, arcamera

How can we access Front Facing Camera Images with `ARCamera` or `ARSCNView` and is it possible to record `ARSCNView` just like Camera Recording?

Answer (score 15):

Regarding the front-facing camera: in short, no.

ARKit offers two basic kinds of AR experience:

- World Tracking (`ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`), using the back-facing camera, where a user looks "through" the device at an augmented view of the world around them. (There's also `AROrientationTrackingConfiguration`, which is a reduced quality version of world tracking, so it still uses only the back-facing camera.)
- Face Tracking (`ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`), supported only with the front-facing TrueDepth camera on iPhone X, where the user sees an augmented view of theirself in the front-facing camera view. (As @TawaNicolas notes, Apple has sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences)... which, until iPhone X actually becomes available, you can read but not run.)

In addition to the hardware requirement, face tracking and world tracking are mostly orthogonal feature sets. So even though there's a way to use the front facing camera (on iPhone X only), it doesn't give you an experience equivalent to what you get with the back facing camera in ARKit.

---

Regarding video recording in the AR experience: you can use [ReplayKit](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit) in an ARKit app same as in any other app.

If you want to record just the camera feed, there isn't a high level API for that, but in theory you might have some success feeding the pixel buffers you get in each `ARFrame` to `AVAssetWriter`.

Comment: is there any Sample code To Record your my ARSCNView

Comment: is there is any Sample Code to To Take Image of my ARSCNView

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, ARKit with Front Facing Camera is only supported for iPhone X.

[Here's Apple's sample code regarding this topic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences).

Comment: so i can track body also using front camera ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the UIKit or AVFoundation cameras, you still can, but separately from ARSCNView. E.g., I'm loading `UIKit's UIImagePickerController` from an `IBAction` and it is a little awkward to do so, but it works for my purposes (loading/creating image and video assets).